# How do I run a django project when it is written in Linux, do I have Windows?

Tags: python, django

I download django-project Linux. Now, I try run it Windows. Project don't have `setting.py` end I don't know how to run it? When I stara t project I have message `module not found`, and I don't know what need to do.

**Manage.py**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "website.settings.dev")
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

**Error**

> File "", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'website.settings'

Answer (score 0):

You can follow following steps to open this project in windows.

**Install git bash:**
Download git for windows from here: https://git-scm.com/downloads.
By default, the python command runs extremely slow or never actually opens up the python interpreter on git bash. To fix this, we need to create an alias for the python command.

Open or create the .bashrc file. This will open the nano editor.

```
nano .bashrc
```

Install pip

Create a virtual environment

Install dependencies

Run the following command in the project path to install dependencies.

```
(venv) $ pip install -r requirements/base.txt
```

Run the project

We are all set to run the project.

Activate environment variables. I create an xport file with environment variables like this.

```
set -a
MAILSERVER="https://MAILURL"
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="myproject.settings.local2"
set +a
```

This enables variables inside this file to be exported. Run the following command in the project path.

```
$ source xport
```

Since it is a lot more trouble to get the actual database to be set up, I create another version of the settings file and configure sqlite as the database.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Run the migrate command to create database structure

```
$ python manage.py migrate
```

Run the built-in webserver

```
$ python manage.py runserver
```